# How to use data-manual in prism.js

Tags: javascript, syntax-highlighting

I'm using [prism.js](http://prismjs.com/index.html) as a syntax highlighter for my website, but I want certain items not te be rendered, like operators and punctuation.

Now, the manual of prism.js states:

> If you want to prevent any elements from being automatically highlighted, you can use the attribute data-manual on the  element you used for prism and use the API. Example:
>
> `<script src="prism.js" data-manual></script>`

But that's it. No further examples. The link to the API only shows some JavaScript functions, but nothing further on `data-manual`. Als if I Google `site:prismjs.com "data-manual"`, no helpful occurances show up.

Can anyone help me on how the illusive `data-manual`-attribute needs to be used?

Answer (score 4):

I think, [here](https://schier.co/blog/2013/01/07/how-to-re-run-prismjs-on-ajax-content.html) is a good example. The credit goes to Gregory Schier.

HTML:

```
<script src="prism.js" data-manual></script>
<pre>
<code id="some-code" class="language-javascript">
  // This is some random code
  var foo = "bar";
</code>
</pre>
```

JavaScript:

```
var block = document.getElementById('some-code');
Prism.highlightElement(block);
```

Answer (score 2):

I also didn't understand how to use data-manual from the documentation--I had to look at the source. Use 'data-manual' when you want to directly call prism's api for adding syntax highlighting. Checkout the [api reference](http://prismjs.com/extending.html#api).

If you don't set data-manual, prism will set up a timeout or listener to call highlightAll (here is the relevant [source](https://github.com/PrismJS/prism/blob/7192ffef12791f65d612d278e97bbcfa852f5b63/prism.js#L492)). This will highlight every element matched by the following selector: `'code[class*="language-"], [class*="language-"] code, code[class*="lang-"], [class*="lang-"] code'`

If you want finer-grained control of timing, or maybe don't want prism adding extra classes, add data-manual to the script tag for the script that contains prismjs, then call highlight yourself. Here's a basic ES6 example of how you might use Prism in manual mode:

```
import {highlight} from 'prismjs';
import 'prismjs/components/prism-python';

const pythonCode = 'myString = "Some String"';
const highlightedCode = highlight(pythonCode, Prism.languages.python);
const highlightedHTML = `<pre><code class="language-python">${highlightedCode}</code></pre>`;
document.getElementById('myID').innerHTML=highlightedHTML;
```